# Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

```
> Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated.
> Use the prop-types package from npm instead.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the React 15.5 release notes here: https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v15.5.0

`React.PropTypes` has been moved to a dedicated package: [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

And here is the migration guide: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html

Personally I use the official [react-codemod](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod) tool to migrate my projects. It can update your projects with a single command.

Comment: Thanks for sharing helpfull links